# Is there a quest to unlock the Torus?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I know that it unlocks when you get to sector 5 with a Kestrel, but I'm asking if there is a specific quest so I can have that empty space in the hangar filled with a nice Q.

Yes, I want to complete **everything** (I'd extend my question to the Kestrel...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the only way to unlock the Torus is to reach Sector 5 with any Kestrel layout (Kestrel, Red-Tail, or Swallow).

[FTL Wiki entry on ships](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Ship#Engi_Cruiser)